# UI-ROUTER $mdDialog

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

I am using the $mdDialog from angular material 1.x with angular 1.7. I have a page that uses ui-views to load some html/controllers.. the purpose of the page is for settings in our application. So navigation on left...and as you click each item it loads the html and controller in ui-view. So below is an example of a route

```
       $stateProvider.state('detail', {
                url: '/setting/detail',

                views: {
                    'complexTemplates': {
                        templateUrl: '{[host]}/app/detail/detail.html',
                        controller: 'DetailController as vm'
                    }
                }
            });
```

And we launch a $mdDialog like this:

```
                       this.$mdDialog.show({
                            parent: angular.element(document.body),
                            controller: 'SettingController',
                            controllerAs: 'settingController',
                            templateUrl: '/app/setting/setting.html',
                            clickOutsideToClose: true,
                            bindToController: true,
                            fullscreen: true

                        })
```

I dont understand how to use the router in a $mdDialog... i see some very WEAK examples out there but none that really fit....

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question? I'm not able to understand what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Rephrase? I want to use a ui-view within an open $mdDialog page. The rest of our application uses ui-router for all navigation. But placing a ui-view inside a $mdDialog doesn’t not work. There is some other tricks with the ui-view name or something to get it to work.